# Getting error while adding new migrations in .NET Core An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object Item [System.String]

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have one entity called `Tabel25Entity`

```cs
public class Tabel25Entity : RootEntity
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I have 3 other entities that they are inheriting from `Tabel25Entity` class:

```cs
public class TimeUnit : Tabel25Entity
    {
        public double ValueInDays { get; set; }
    }

public class ExtraInfo : Tabel25Entity
    {
        public int DurationFactor { get; set; }
        public double MinimumDosageFrequency { get; set; }
        public double MaximumDosageFrequency { get; set; }
        public double MinimumDosePerOccasion { get; set; }
        public double MaximumDosePerOccasion { get; set; }
        public ExtraInfoCategory Category { get; set; }
    }

public class Usage : Tabel25Entity
    {
        public double ReferenceQuantity { get; set; }
        public string MeasurementUnitCode { get; set; }
        public string MeasurementUnitDescription { get; set; }
        public string BaseUnitCode { get; set; }
        public string BaseUnitName { get; set; }
    }
```

Also, another entity called `ExtraInfoCategory`

```cs
public class ExtraInfoCategory : RootEntity
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsParsable { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to add new migration but I am getting following error:

```
PM> Add-Migration Tabel25ToRootEntity -v
Using project 'DosageParsing\DataAccess\DosageParsing.Persistence.DbMigrations'.
Using startup project 'DosageParsing\WebApi\DosageParsing.WebApi'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile "C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\WebApi\WebApi\bin\Debug\net6.0\SmartMed.DosageParsing.WebApi.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\Kamran\.nuget\packages --runtimeconfig "C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\WebApi\WebApi\bin\Debug\net6.0\SmartMed.DosageParsing.WebApi.runtimeconfig.json" C:\Users\Kamran\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\7.0.4\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add Tabel25ToRootEntity --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly "C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\WebApi\WebApi\bin\Debug\net6.0\SmartMed.DosageParsing.Persistence.DbMigrations.dll" --project "C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\DA\Persistence.DbMigrations\DosageParsing.Persistence.DbMigrations.csproj" --startup-assembly "C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\WebApi\WebApi\bin\Debug\net6.0\SmartMed.DosageParsing.WebApi.dll" --startup-project "C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\WebApi\WebApi\DosageParsing.WebApi.csproj" --project-dir "C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\DA\Persistence.DbMigrations\\" --language C# --configuration Debug --working-dir "C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd" --root-namespace SmartMed.DosageParsing.Persistence.DbMigrations
Using assembly 'SmartMed.DosageParsing.Persistence.DbMigrations'.
Using startup assembly 'SmartMed.DosageParsing.WebApi'.
Using application base 'C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\WebApi\WebApi\bin\Debug\net6.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\WebApi\WebApi'.
Using root namespace 'SmartMed.DosageParsing.Persistence.DbMigrations'.
Using project directory 'C:\SmartMed\Repos\Tasks\59355\SmartMed BackEnd\DosageParsing\DA\Persistence.DbMigrations\'.
Remaining arguments: .
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'SmartMed.DosageParsing.WebApi'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Found DbContext 'DosageParsingDbContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'DosageParsingDbContext'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'SmartMed.DosageParsing.WebApi'...
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'SmartMed.DosageParsing.Persistence.DbMigrations'...
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'SmartMed.DosageParsing.WebApi'...
No design-time services were found.
The property 'ExtraInfo.CategoryId' was created in shadow state because there are no eligible CLR members with a matching name.
The property 'ExtraInfoCategory.CreatedActor#Actor.ExtraInfoCategoryId' was created in shadow state because there are no eligible CLR members with a matching name.
The property 'ExtraInfoCategory.UpdatedActor#Actor.ExtraInfoCategoryId' was created in shadow state because there are no eligible CLR members with a matching name.
The property 'Tabel25Entity.CreatedActor#Actor.Tabel25EntityId' was created in shadow state because there are no eligible CLR members with a matching name.
The property 'Tabel25Entity.UpdatedActor#Actor.Tabel25EntityId' was created in shadow state because there are no eligible CLR members with a matching name.
The property 'Tabel25CodeShortcut.CreatedActor#Actor.Tabel25CodeShortcutId' was created in shadow state because there are no eligible CLR members with a matching name.
The property 'Tabel25CodeShortcut.UpdatedActor#Actor.Tabel25CodeShortcutId' was created in shadow state because there are no eligible CLR members with a matching name.
DetectChanges starting for 'DosageParsingDbContext'.
DetectChanges completed for 'DosageParsingDbContext'.
DetectChanges starting for 'DosageParsingDbContext'.
DetectChanges completed for 'DosageParsingDbContext'.
'DosageParsingDbContext' disposed.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object Item [System.String]
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetSortedProperties(IEntityType entityType, ITable table)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetSortedColumns(ITable table)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Add(ITable target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object Item [System.String]
```

So, can you tell me why I am getting this error?

I updated EF Core packages but seems they have other problems (then downgraded then).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this to your Data Project, adding your Namespace:

```
namespace FourPointImport.Data
{
    public class DesignTimeDbContext : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApiDbContext>
    {
        IConfiguration _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        
        public ApiDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApiDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            return new ApiDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

}